# The wall was built "from bricks" or "of bricks"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

The wall was built from bricks.

The wall was built of bricks.

Which sentence is more correct and is there any difference?

Comment: Paper is made **from** wood, but a wooden furniture is made **of** wood.

Comment: Ngram = 'Built from'/'Built of'/'Built out of'.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=built+from%2Cbuilt+of%2Cbuilt+out+of&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuilt%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuilt%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuilt%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say *The wall was built **of** bricks* is more correct.

Consider these two sentences:

> Paper is made **from** wood.
>
> The frame is made **of** wood.

Here, **of** indicates direct material. The frame is constructed by cutting and combining wood. **for** indicates indirect material. Paper is made by processing wood through a lot of complex procedures, after which it's no longer wood.

The same applies to "build". Since the wall is built by piling bricks up and mounting them, no complex procedure that makes brick lose its attributes exist. Therefore it's better to say *is built **of** bricks*.